# Get XPages to play nice with Google

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to get Google to play nicely with the XPage for SNoUG. When I enter 'snoug' in google, the main title is a reference to an old post referring to our event of last year, which is kind of embarrassing...

[image]

It's not clear to me how Google found it's title, since that's a really old post. I've told Google that I'm the webmaster, by using a theme with the relevant authentication code in a meta tag. I've asked Google to re-index but no bananas.

--> Do you know how the title which is displayed is calculated?

I've built a sitemap.xml but I'm not sure which is the best place

--> What's the best place for a sitemap.xml?

The XPages is multilingual and shows different titles based on the browser language. I looked at the Google documentation and they are expecting different addresses, which of course I don't have.

--> Do you know how to teach Google to display different results based on the language of the browser of the person entering the search term?

I'm grateful for any help. I saw that Per Hendrik Lausten made a custom control which allows to control the meta tags, but I'm not sure that this would answer any of my questions.

**Update/Answer:**
Howard pointed me in the right direction, I'm writing the answer here so that he can make a proper answer and collect the SO brownie points.

I created a sitemap.xml file following Google's spec, this is what it looks like:

```
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/home.xsp</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/registration.xsp
</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/agenda.xsp</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/sessions.xsp
</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/speakers.xsp
</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/sponsors.xsp
</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/faqs.xsp</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/archive.xsp</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

And then I inserted it into my project in the proper place using Package Explorer.

[image]

The last step is giving Google via the Webmaster page the url of the sitemap. That produced a relatively speedy reindex of the site.

Comment: Did you get a Google webmaster account? You can specify the location of a sitemap and do all sorts of config. on searches with that.

Comment: Agree with Howard. Set up a Google Webmaster account and add your site including a link to your sitemap.xml. Then Google will re-index your site.

Comment: It looks like you can [drive a sitemap.xml from a View](http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tips.nsf/0/51D89CC0D19A598C85257148006BC426) or you could just create one and park it in your NSF's WebContent dir.

Comment: I've got the account. Will report on results. Thanks guys

Comment: done. Worked well, now to see what Google does with it.

Comment: I got my reindexing happy bunny now!

Comment: @Howard -> turn your comment into an answer, so we can give you proper credit

Comment: what's this? http://www.snoug.ch/SNOUG/webX-New.nsf/$defaultView :-)

Comment: haha Patrick - any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Sure, turned my comment into an answer since I need 2 points to get to 1,000 (woohoo!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get a Google webmaster account? You can specify the location of a sitemap and do all sorts of config. on searches with that.

Howard